# A question on a Lipschitz function

Tags: analysis, limits, continuity

This is the problem:

Prove or disprove the following statement:

If $f:[0,+\infty]\rightarrow\mathbb{R^+}$  is a Lipschitz function and not bounded, then it has necessarily $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = +\infty$

Comment: What's your intuition for why it's true?

Comment: I can not find functions with these characteristics for which the limit is not + inf

Comment: What do you mean by "not limited"?

Comment: the set of the image of f is unlimited

Comment: In English you say "bounded", not "limited".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
T(x)=1-2\,|1-x|,\quad 0\le x\le1
$$
be the *tent* function. Now define $f$ as $f(x)=0$ if $0\le x\le1$ and
$$
f(x)=2^nT(2^{-n}(x-2^n))\quad \text{if}\quad 2^n\le x\le2^{n+1}.
$$
[image]

$f$ is Lipsthitz with constant $2$, unbounded, and $f(2^n)=0$ for all $n$, so that $f(x)\not\to\infty$. If you want $f$ to be strictly positive, just take $f(x)+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather synthetic example:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 \phantom{-}0 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
 \phantom{-}2(x - 1) & 1 \leq x \leq 2 \\
 -2(x - 2) + 2 & 2 \leq x \leq 3 \\
 \phantom{-}2(x - 3) & 3 \leq x \leq 6 \\
 -2(x - 6) + 6 & 6 \leq x \leq 9 \\
 \phantom{-}\dots & \\
 \phantom{-}2(x - 3^n) & 3^n \leq x \leq 2\cdot 3^n \\
 -2(x - 2\cdot 3^n) + 2\cdot 3^n & 2\cdot 3^n \leq x \leq 3^{n + 1}
\end{cases}$$
If I got my numbers right, this should move in a sawtooth manner between $y = 0$ and $y = x$ with slope $\pm 2$, and is thus an unbounded Lipschitz function with positive values.  It suggests the following smooth version:
$$g(x) = x \sin^2 (1 + x)^{-1/3}.$$
We have
$$g'(x) = \sin^2 (1 + x)^{-1/3} - \frac{1}{3} x(1 + x)^{-4/3} \sin 2(1 + x)^{-1/3},$$
which is bounded, so $g$ is Lipschitz, and $g$ is unbounded since $\sin^2 (1 + x)^{-1/3} \sim (1 + x)^{-2/3}$ as $x \to \infty$, which is overpowered by the factor of $x$.

I consider the synthetic example more convincing than the smooth example, despite the compactness of the formula.  It demonstrates that even if you can't *find* an example, it is possible to construct one by imagining how it would look; as the now-deleted previous answers demonstrate, it can be rather tricky to get a "simple" formula to work out calculus-wise.